# Problem measuring frequency and phase of the grid using 4046 PLL and Phase Comparator I

Tags: pll

In my project, I need to determine the phase & frequency of the sin wave grid (50 Hz). For this purpose, I used a CD 4046 PLL and a LM311 op amp to produce square signal input for pin 14 (based on data sheet). my questions are:

1. Can  this IC (4046) determine the phase & frequency for this frequency range?
2. Frequency of the out put VCO (pin 4)  is 34.5 KHz; while input signal frequency (SIG_IN) is 50 Hz.
3. How can I determine the grid frequency (for example 50 Hz) with this IC?
4. How can I determine the phase of the grid while output VCO frequency is higher than input frequency (50 Hz)?

Comment: What/ where is your accurate reference for time or frequency?  VCO f is reduced by Vc and larger RC values as per spec.

Comment: Basically, you want someone to figure out this whole assignment for you. You are tasked to determine the phase and frequency, and you ask how to determine the phase and frequency.

Comment: define input deviation and expected outputs ; analog, digital,  resolution accuracy then choose frequency reference that is more accurate

Answer (score 0):

By itself, the 4046 can tell you neither frequency nor phase.

The 4046 can be used to do the following things:

1. Generate a new signal with a frequency at some multiple of the original (the multiple can be one or higher)
2. Detect the phase of a signal in relation to another signal (using just the phase detector.)

To detect the line frequency, you need a frequency counter of some kind.

Using it as a multiplier with a factor of one is easy but pointless.  You could just use the original signal in that case.

To generate a higher frequency, you need a divider between the oscillator output and the phase detector input

To use it as a phase detector, you need a reference signal to compare to.

The 4046 is really not good for high frequencies, but should work well at 50Hz.  I remember seeing a 4046 used in a frequency synthesizer for a VHF radio.  The RF was divided down to 5kHz so that the 4046 could work comfortably within its bandwidth.

---

I once built an RPM indicator that used a 4046 to multiply a single impulse per rotation by 60 so that a frequency counter could be used to display the RPM.  3000 RPM is 50Hz, so that's right in your ball park.

That was like 20 years ago.

Why do you want to use  a 4046?
What makes you think you can use it as a frequency counter and phase detector?

Comment: This IC was introduced to me. What do you offer that in this frequency range (50 Hz) detect grid phase and frequency

Comment: For phase, you have to have a reference.  For frequency, you have to have a counter.  The 4046 has neither a reference for the nor a counter for the frequency.  What were you told by whoever told you to use the 4046?  At any rate, you can easily build a frequency counter for 50Hz using any microprocessor and a zero crossing detector.  Or do you just need to see when phase and/or frequency change?  You could use the 4046 for that, but you can't measure the frequency or the phase.  You can only see when they change.

Comment: The DC driving the 4046 oscillator will be proportional to the frequency, but probably not precise enough to do any good.